# Is it possible to align a div to the bottom of a div with position: fixed?

Tags: css, position, css-position, vertical-alignment, fixed

I'm trying to create a sort of navigational footer that only displays when the mouse hovers over it. The hover zone is 10% of the screen height but the links are fixed along the bottom of the window. Everything is working fine, but I would like to have a 50px tall white background below the text links at the very bottom to make the links easier to see, for example above image, text, etc.

I could make the entire "hover" div white, but I would really prefer to have just a smaller are at the bottom. Sorry if this is a little unclear—I've created a fiddle to illustrate. Please bear in mind that the colors are only for illustration purposes. None of the divs will have background colors except for the #white_bg div at the very bottom.

I found some posts on here about aligning a div with position: absolute to the bottom of a div with position: relative, but unfortunately I think I need to have fixed positioning on my containing div.

Here is a quick sketch showing what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Here's the code I am using:

```
<div class="nav-bottom hidden-xs">
    <div id="white_bg">
        <div class="bottom-nav-left hidden-xs">Information</div>    
        <div  class="bottom-nav-right hidden-xs">Index &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Next project</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS and all the rest is in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/09kj9hpq

I'm also open to other suggestions of how to achieve this. Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: "I think I need to have fixed positioning on my containing div"  That's OK, **you can still position something absolutely to a fixed position div**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Paulie_D. I tried using absolute positioning on the #white_bg div but it just doesn't show up. Maybe I'm doing something else wrong? Were you able to get it to work in the fiddle? Thanks!!! P.S. I just added an image to better illustrate what I'm trying to do…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/09kj9hpq/7/)

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.nav-bottom {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 10%;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: cyan;
    /* bg color for purposes of this demo only */
}
#white_bg {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;
}
.bottom-nav-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 20px;
}
.bottom-nav-right {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 20px;
}
.nav-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .125s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .125s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .05s;
    -o-transition: opacity .125s;
}
.nav-bottom:link { /* not required as divs children*/
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .125s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .125s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .05s;
    -o-transition: opacity .125s;
}
.nav-bottom:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .125s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .125s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .05s;
    -o-transition: opacity .125s;

 }
```

Comment: this is EXACTLY what I was after, thank you so so much! Just so I can understand, I think you just changed the positioning on #white_bg to absolute and added width: 100%? I tried absolute positioning before but I think maybe nothing showed up because I didn't set a width? Could that have been the problem?

Comment: i changed the positioning on all the children to absolute...and the width thing, yes, that seems likely

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I answer your question by this, but I hope my answer is usefull for you. I created a fiddle for you to clearify myself: http://jsfiddle.net/r8mwcwk2/. The code for the footer (which I believe is going to be your white space) is the following:

```
#footer {
    background-color:blue;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    font-family:helvetica;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, but I'm not quite sure it's exactly what I need. To clarify, I think I need to have a couple of divs nested inside. The outer div (.nav-bottom) will have fixed positioning and be at the very bottom of the screen with height: 10%. This will be the "hover zone". Everything inside this div will have opacity: 0 until the mouse hovers over this div. Inside this I hoped to have a 50px high div with a white background and some text links inside. I added an image above to help illustrate :0)

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/g30rmufy/. Make sure that the height of your result screen is high enough.

Comment: No problem! Just a pleasure :)